# Old Sony Sound Forge versions

Tags: audio, audio-recording, installer

I still have a valid license (serial number, etc.) for Sony Sound Forge 8 and 9, but I can't find the installer anymore. I'm looking for files named:

```
soundforge90d_enu.exe
```

(http://download.sonymediasoftware.com/current/soundforge90d_enu.exe is outdated: *"We're sorry, the page you're looking for can't be found."*)

```
soundforge80d.exe
```

(http://download.sonymediasoftware.com/current/soundforge80d.exe is outdated)

**Question: is there still an official source for Sound Forge 8 and 9 installers?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after posting the question, I found them thanks to Archive.org's Wayback Machine:

https://web.archive.org/web/20160402193613/http://download.sonymediasoftware.com/current/soundforge70b.exe

https://web.archive.org/web/20160402195949/http://download.sonymediasoftware.com/current/soundforge80d.exe

https://web.archive.org/web/20170227084412/http://download.sonymediasoftware.com/current/soundforge90d_enu.exe